# Does nvcc use cl.exe to compiler both .cpp and .cu files in windows?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, nvcc, cl

I know nvcc only compiles `.cu` files, and pass `.c` or `.cpp` to designated compilers like gcc, g++, clang, clang++, etc...

Here's my problem.
Thrust headers in `.h` file in Windows which uses cl.exe complied just fine.
But the same codes in Linux with g++ or clang++ didn't compile complaining no such headers like `thrust/device_vector.h` and so on.

So my theory is: Windows nvcc uses cl.exe to compile both `.cpp` and `.cu`, which means `cl.exe` can compile Thrust or CUDA related codes.
Linux on the other hand, Linux nvcc uses CUDA compiler to compile `.cu` and g++ or clang++ to compile `.cpp` files, which means `.h` or `.cpp` files with Thrust or CUDA related code cannot be compiled with.

It that right?
If not, why can Windows nvcc compile `.h` with Thrust, but Linux nvcc cannot?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example and the compilation commands for all cases

Comment: nvcc uses host compilers for host code independent of that code being in a `.cu`or `.cpp` file. Host compilers generally can't compile device code (kernels, device functions). Certain Thrust headers contain device code and should therefore only be included from a `.cu` file.

Answer (score 2):

The compilation process is similar for Linux and Windows. The NVCC compiler driver separates host and device code, then invokes your platform's C++ compiler. For more information, refer to [this section of the NVCC documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#the-cuda-compilation-trajectory).

Thrust headers are not included in the search path by default when using `g++` or `clang++`, however you can provide it explicitly using the `-I` flag. Example below with a simple C++ file including CUDA and Thrust headers:

```bash
$ cat test.cc
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

int main(void)
{
}
$ g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ test.cc -o test
$ ./test
```

Comment: while this resolves the missing include, device_vector for the CUDA back-end cannot be instantiated in code compiled with g++ because instantiation requires kernel compilation.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor while the CUDA runtime API requires compilation using `nvcc`, you can run kernels from pure C/C++ code using the CUDA driver API by loading precompiled binaries (see [Module Management section of the CUDA driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__MODULE.html)). NVIDIA also provide APIs to JIT-compile PTX or CUDA code (see [NVRTC](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nvrtc/index.html) for more information).